# Dynamic matrix in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I am working with a multidimensional array but i get an exception, i have searched a lot but i find the same answer i'm using, the exception jumps when i try to allocate matriz[i] = new double[n]. I have tried both the commented and uncommented solutions with no luck.

```
void interpol(double *arr_x, double *arr_y, int n, double *results) {
    //double** matriz = new double*[n];
    double** matriz;
    matriz = (double**) malloc(n * sizeof(double*));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){    
        //matriz[i] = new double[n+1];
        matriz[i] = (double*) malloc(n+1 * sizeof(double));
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = pow(arr_x[i],j);
        }
        matriz[i][n] = arr_y[i];
    }
    gaussiana(matriz, n, results);
}
```

--- EDIT---

The function gaussiana is working fine, since i have tested outside this function. The exception is thrown in either:
 //matriz[i] = new double[n];
   matriz[i] = (double*) malloc(n * sizeof(double));

n is never more than 10.

The exception thrown is:

> First-chance exception at 0x00071c4d in Interpolacion.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation     reading location 0x00000000.
>       Unhandled exception at 0x774b15de in Interpolacion.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
>       The program '[8012] Interpolacion.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).

----EDIT----
I finally got it working, the issue was not in matriz, but with arr_x/arr_y, the external routine was sending the data wrong (oddly the error and the stacktrace always referred me to the new double[n] assignation)

Comment: Should the `255` actually be `n`? Otherwise you may run over the array bounds. Anyway, this is terrible code. If you want a rectangular matrix, you might just use a flattened, 1-D array, or even better something like Boost.MultiArray. Naked pointers are generally bad style in C++.

Comment: What is the value of n when you call this function? I bet it is more then 255.

Comment: @KerrekSB sorry the 255 bit was just a test i ran, but i have tried it with n. I will try Boost.MultiArray thank you.

Comment: @izomorphius actually for the tests n has values of no more than 5

Comment: Not about your problem, but you forget to free the allocated data at the end of the function, and have a memory leak.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using `std::vector`? I feel it will heavily relieve your memory management duties.

Comment: @dreamlax I'm kind of new to C++, how would i use a multidimensional vector?

Comment: @Rockiano: Something like `std::vector<std::vector<double> > matriz;` (that is, a vector of vectors).

Comment: Using std::vector<> of size X*Y will also be easy, given that you write accesor function... (x,y) = V[x+y*size_x].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `std::vector` route, you can use something like below (untested, shown just as a guide). Keep in mind that `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` is not compatible with `double **`, so your `gaussiana` function might need to be rewritten to accept the new type.:

```
// Include the header!
#include <vector>


// Be careful about the use of "using namespace std", I'm only using it here
// because it's a small example
using namespace std;

vector<vector<double> > matriz;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    // Create a new vector "v" with n+1 elements
    vector<double> v(n + 1);

    // fill this vector
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        v[j] = pow(arr_x[i], j);
    v[n] = arr_y[i];   

    // add it to the matrix
    matriz.push_back(v);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this solution today, although I finally got it working, the issue was not in matriz, but with arr_x, the external routine was sending the data wrong (oddly the error and the stacktrace always referred me to the new double[n] assignation)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the code present which would cause an exception.  It must be `gaussiana()` causing the trouble.  Try commenting that line out and see if the program still faults.

It would be useful to know the range of `n`.  As long as it is relatively small (< 1000) on modern 32- or 64-bit machines, `malloc()` should not fail.  However, if the program runs with restricted memory, or `n` is large, it is likely that some `malloc`s would fail.  Since there is no checking for NULL being returned, the program would indicate trouble by SEGFAULTing when trying to dereference the pointer.

If the function is called multiple times, the memory leaking could add up to a significant heap shortage and induce `malloc()` to fail.

Comment: On some modern operating systems, `malloc` will return a valid pointer even if there is not enough memory left (I think it's called overcommitting or something).

Comment: @dreamlax:  What operating system would do that?  `malloc()`'s error handling was pretty clearly specified in original C.

Comment: Linux does it (or at least it did, not sure if it still does). I can't remember which distro I was using, but I had 2GB of RAM and I asked for 2GB of memory from `malloc()`, and it worked, and it only crashed when I tried to use it all (i.e. write a byte to each page). The process got killed by the "OOM Killer".